# is it necessary to consider the screen resolution 1280x600 while creating responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am creating a responsive game web site. for that i don't want `scroll bar` in any resolution. i am using to test my website mozila `"Responsive design View"`. in that they provided some standard screen resolution. I am OK with all resolution except `1280x600,` And now  my quesion is ...

```
1. Is there any devices in this resolution?
2. How many people are using this type of devices?
3. is it necessary to consider this resolution while creating responsive website?
```

Please replay me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, you should handle any resolution (or at least those over some fairly small minimum size).  Even if no one uses a display with that native resolution, not everyone always runs their browsers in maximized windows.  And I would not be surprised at all if some smartphone or netbook uses a 1280x600 display.

Comment: @Keshav, did either of our answers below help solve your issue? thx~

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to desktop computers, screen resolution means nothing because a user can change the size of his browser window to any width and height. This means you may have a "resolution" of "1280x600 pixels" one moment, and "1281x599 pixels" the next.

Responsive design should gracefully accommodate all browser window sizes. All you need to worry is break points (i.e. your media queries), where page layout changes. Most designers typically set 2-3 break points to match the most commonly used screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of that exact ratio, 1280x600 pixels.

Here are some quick statistical resources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-na-monthly-200903-201203